# How to create cube slide transition in Libreoffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

I'm creating a presentation using Libreoffice Impress. How can I make it so that when the presentation goes from one slide to the next, they rotate like a cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Impress, choose the menu options *SlideShow* -> *Slide Transitions*.  Way down the list you will find *Outside turning cube* and *Inside turning cube*.  These are the slide transitions that I believe you want.